# thou/you and art/are In Shakespeare's sonnets

Tags: meaning, word-usage, shakespeare

Is there a consistent application of any distinction between the forms of the words thou and you, and art and are in Shakespeare's sonnets? Is he simply following a convention regarding formality in diction, or can a case be made that he is trying to create something more in terms of meaning by his choice in a specific case?

Comment: Yes, there can be a significance.  There is an interesting article on it by Dr Mark Womack of the University of Houston in http://drmarkwomack.com/engl-3306/handouts/shakespeares-language/thou-and-you-in-shakespeare/.  Better still, Andrew Gurr published a book on the subject back in 1982.  But this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: This seems pretty broad. "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." And someone has: [Shakespeare's Use of the Pronoun of Address: Its Significance in Characterization and Motivation](https://books.google.com/books?id=ViZ4I8ucUIsC).

Comment: The use of _thou_ and _you_ was changing around that time, and Shakespeare was no more concerned with being consistent in his spelling or grammar than anybody else of the time, which means not at all. For the record, _thou_ agrees with _art_ (but _we,  you_, and _they_ agree with _are_); in addition, _thee_ and _ye_ (like _me_) are objective pronouns, and can't appear as subjects.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think you switched _you_ and _ye_ there. Originally, _ye_ was the subject pronoun and _you_ the object pronoun. By Shakespeare’s time, that was already messed up and both pronouns could have both functions, but I don’t think there was ever a period in English where _ye_ could **only** appear as object and not as subject.

Answer (score -2):

I think his use of the terms reflects the then current use and is not a special use or device of any kind.

Comment: You 'think' would perhaps be better if you could add some evidence